# Infer prop type based on value being presnt

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, type-inference, inference

I have a very simple example of what i'm trying to achieve, basically when the entity prop is present, i want the onClick callback to receive the entity string, if not it would receive nothing

```
type SnakeOrCamelDomains = "light" | "switch" | "input_boolean" | "fan";
interface TestProps<S extends `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}`> {
  entity?: S;
  onClick: S extends `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}` ? (entity: string) => void : () => void;
}

function Test<S extends `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}`>({
  entity,
  onClick,
}: TestProps<S>) {
    return <button onClick={() => {
      if (typeof entity === 'string') {
        onClick(entity);
      } else {
        onClick();
      }
    }}>{entity}</button>
}
```

This example above doesn't work with typescript, it's expecting me to pass an argument to onClick, naturually... as typescript doesn't know anything about entity or it's value at this point.

Is this possible with typescript?

Comment: Did you try with `onClick: (entity?: SnakeOrCamelDomains) => void;`

Comment: how would that help @Jacek? I'm expecting the value to be a string or undefined...

Comment: Correct, I rushed too fast, the type should be string. Then it'll be `onClick: (entity?: string) => void;`. `entity?: string` means that the parameter named `entity` is optional so you can pass either string value or undefined.

Comment: That's not what i'm asking mate, the question is how to infer the type based on the entity string being present, i don't want users to have to check that entity exists because i've forced it to be optional... @Jacek

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having this error is because the type `S` is a subtype of `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}`, and because of that, TypeScript expects `S` to always be a string.

Even though `entity` is optional and could be undefined, TypeScript still infers `onClick` as `(entity: string) => void` due to `S` always extending `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}`.

If you want the `onClick` function to be optionally called with an entity, you can change its type to a function that takes an optional string argument:

```js
interface TestProps<S extends `${SnakeOrCamelDomains}.${string}`> {
  entity?: S;
  onClick: (entity?: string) => void;
}
```

Comment: That isn't what I'm after, this all provide intellisense that entity is available when you don't provide the prop, which is incorrect

Comment: <Test entity="light.something" onClick={(entity) => {
  console.log('entity', entity)
}}></Test>

I would expect entity to be available

<Test  onClick={(entity) => {
  // this should have typescript errors
}}></Test>

Comment: It's also not infering the value to be defined when providing the entity prop